# Specify layout of global variables in C

Tags: c, gcc, opengl

Consider this piece of code, where two global variables are defined:

```c
int a;
int b;
```

As far as I know, the compiler may or may not place `a` and `b` in adjacent memory locations (please let me know if this is incorrect). For example, with GCC one may compile with `-fdata-sections` and reorder the two sections or whatever.

Is it possible to specify that `a` and `b` must be adjacent (in the sense that `&a + 1 == &b`), in either standard or  GNU extended C?

Background: I am making an OpenGL loader, which is literally (omitting casts):

```c
void (*glActiveShaderProgram)(GLuint, GLuint);
void (*glActiveTexture)(GLenum);
...

void load_gl(void (*(*loader)(char *))()) {
    glActiveShaderProgram = load("glActiveShaderProgram");
    glActiveTexture = load("glActiveTexture");
    ...
}
```

Simple enough, but every call to `load` compiles into a call to `load`. Since there is a relatively large number of functions to load, that can take up a lot of code space. (That is the reason I dropped *glad*.)

So I had something like this, which reduces binary size by ~30kB, which is extremely important for me:

```c
char names[] = "glActiveShaderProgram glActiveTexture ...";
char *p = names, *pp;
for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i) {
    pp = strchr(names, ' ');
    *pp = '\0';
    (&glActiveShaderProgram)[i] = load(p);
    p = pp + 1;
}
```

But this does assume the specific layout of these function pointers. Currently I wrap the function pointers in a struct which is type-punned into an array of pointers, like this:

```c
union { struct {
    void (*glActiveShaderProgram)(GLuint, GLuint);
    void (*glActiveTexture)(GLenum);
    ...
}; void (*table[COUNT])(); } gl;
```

But then one `#define` for every function is required to make the user happy. So I wonder if there exists some more elegant way to specify the layout of global variables.

Comment: `int ab[2];` should work

Comment: "compiler may or may not place a and b in adjacent memory locations" --> Correct.  Even if adjacent, a possible variation is order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ted suggested in the comment. You could put the variables next to each other inside an array?

```
int ab[2] = {a, b};
```

Another way to ensure adjacent memory placement is with a packed struct. [example](https://riptutorial.com/c/example/31059/packing-structures)

[more info](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)

Comment: Array specifies the 2 `int` are adjacent.  A `struct`  certainly also results in adjacent `int` along as no padding.  With `int` types, no padding is certain but specified.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the `union` is unnecessary, my code is now a lot simpler. However the `#define`s are still there, maybe there is nothing we can do about it.